# Swift 4 and SpriteKit: Move node to a new touch location

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, swift4

I'm trying to move a node to a touch location using physicsBody (as opposed to SKAction). I am trying to use applyForce, but I may be going about this wrong.

In my touchesBegan function I record the touch location in a constant and pass it into my movePlayer function. The initial touch works as expected. However, subsequent touches seem to move from a relative position, which makes me think that I should recalculate my vector. I'm just not sure how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

```
func movePlayer(to touchPoint: CGPoint) {
    let vector = CGVector(dx: touchPoint.x, dy: touchPoint.y)
    player.physicsBody?.applyForce(vector, at: player.position)
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = vector
    playerIsMoving = true
}
```

Comment: It seems like you are applying movement to the player twice... once with `applyForce` and again when you set the player's velocity to the vector.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I thought the same thing, too. The problem is the node hardly moves at all if I don't add the velocity, i.e. comment that line out. I did get my vector math sorted out for the applyForce, but i still can't get the velocity working right.

Comment: Are you sure that your player sprite and the touches are all using the same coordinate system? Depending on your setup, it's possible that some things may be using the scene's coordinate system while other things are using the view's coordinate system. Sometimes there can be a difference between the two which may account for the offset you described. It's hard to visualize exactly what you are experiencing without seeing the funky movement.

Comment: The anchor points for the scene and node are set to be the same. Is that what you mean? If not, could you explain further please? Thanks.

Comment: You might use print statements to check the position of the touches and the vector value every time a touch occurs. And a print statement in your update method that prints the player's position every frame. Then see if those numbers are all what you expect them to be. If not then it may indicate that something is off with your coordinates. You can print the position of your scene's anchor point and compare that to all the other points that you are printing. The only other thing I'd suggest is to create a test project that duplicates the problem and put it on Github so others can take a look.

Comment: you do not want to apply it to the player position, just use `player.physicsBody?.applyForce(vector)`  You are applying the force too far away from the player,  that is why he is barely moving

Comment: Thank you both for your help. The suggestion that I was applying movement twice led me in the right direction. I fiddled around with it and got my calculations to work out pretty close to what I want.

Comment: To add a bit, I would look into applyForce() vs applyImpulse(), you use Force when applied over a period of time. it only lasts for 1 update cycle I believe, so you  have to continuously call the applyForce() to get it to move constantly. applyImpulse() might be what you are looking for.